# erase iterator from list in debug and release mode?

Tags: c++

I have a strange problem here. I'm trying to erase an iterator from a particle system (std::list). I erase an iterator when the particles goes out of screen. When I checked the size of the particles in debug mode, I found that they are the double compared to release mode, I don't know why.

Kindly find the following code

```
 void ParticleManager::update(std::vector<ci::Vec2f> masses)
    {
        int targetDifference = masses.size() - m_Targets.size();

        if (masses.size() == 1 && targetDifference == 1)
        {
            addTarget();
        }
        else if (targetDifference > 1)
        {
            addTarget();
        } 
        else if (targetDifference < 0)
        {
            deleteTarget();
        }

        Vec2f currVec, offset;
        float fCurrLengthSquared;
        bool bAllTargetsActive = true;

        std::list<Particle>::iterator p = m_Particles.begin();
        while( p != m_Particles.end() ) 
        {
            p->update();

            float fMinSquaredLength = 0.0f;

            // influence of the masses
            for( int i = 0; i < (int) masses.size(); ++i )
            {
                currVec = masses[i] - p->m_Position;
                fCurrLengthSquared = currVec.lengthSquared();

                if (fCurrLengthSquared < ParamMgr.m_fForceMinDist * ParamMgr.m_fForceMinDist)
                {
                    fCurrLengthSquared = ParamMgr.m_fForceMinDist * ParamMgr.m_fForceMinDist;
                }

                if(fCurrLengthSquared < ParamMgr.m_fForceMaxDist * ParamMgr.m_fForceMaxDist)
                {
                    offset = currVec.normalized() / (fCurrLengthSquared / 500.0f);  // 1000.0f      
                    p->m_Direction += offset * ((float) TimerMgr.getDeltaTime() * ParamMgr.m_fGravity * ParamMgr.m_fGravity );
                }

                /*if( i == 0 )
                    fMinSquaredLength = fCurrLengthSquared;

                if( fCurrLengthSquared < fMinSquaredLength )
                    fMinSquaredLength = fCurrLengthSquared;*/
            }

            if( masses.size() > 0 )
            {
                float fSquareColorRadius = ParamMgr.m_fColorRadius * ParamMgr.m_fColorRadius;
                if( fMinSquaredLength > fSquareColorRadius )
                fMinSquaredLength = fSquareColorRadius;

                float fIntensity = 1.0f - (fMinSquaredLength / fSquareColorRadius) * 0.9f;
                //p->m_Color = ci::Color(0.0f, fIntensity, 0.0f);
                //p->m_Color = ci::Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            }

            p->m_fAge += (float) TimerMgr.getDeltaTime();

            // outside the window
            if( p->m_Position.x < 0.0f - m_fCollisionOffsetX || p->m_Position.x > getWindowWidth() + m_fCollisionOffsetX ||
                p->m_Position.y < 0.0f - m_fCollisionOffsetY || p->m_Position.y > getWindowHeight() + m_fCollisionOffsetY )
            {
                p->m_bIsDead = true;
            }
            else
            { 
                // check targets
                for( std::list<Target>::iterator t = m_Targets.begin(); t != m_Targets.end(); t++ )
                {
                    if( t->checkParticle( p->m_Position ) )
                    {
                        p->m_ColorChange = Color( CM_HSV, t->m_fHue, t->m_fSat * 0.9f, 1.0f );
                        if( p->checkTarget( *t ) )
                        {
                            t->addParticleHit();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if( t != m_Targets.end() )
                        {
                            p->m_Targets.remove( *t );
                            //std::cout << "Try to erase: " << (*t).m_Position << " from target list." << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   

            if( p->m_bIsDead )
            {
                p = m_Particles.erase(p);

            }   
                p++;
}
```

Comment: how do inspect the size in release?

Comment: I see the speed depends on real time, which means it depends on frame rate. This can often cause different behaviour between release and debug. Could it be something so simple?

Comment: @izomorphius I just cout<<m_Particles.size();

Comment: @Agentlien does the size also depend on the framerate?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: That depends on your implementation. Also, try to avoid `std::list` if it is not absolutely necessary. Often a `std::vector` is much faster and less memory consumptive, especially when you are removing all objects at once.

Comment: it is strange, the particles size at release is 257 and in debug is 514, typically the half!
erase doesn't work the same in debug or release?!

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: erase works the same in release & debug.  Undefined behavior caused by using invalid iterators, not so much.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Constantinius This particular application (where single elements are often removed from the middle of a sequence) seems much better suited to `std::list` than to `std::vector` -- with a vector, each time you remove an element, you have to copy/move all the elements that follow it.

Comment: @EdwardLoper: I'd still object. `std::list` have a *way* worse cache coherence than `std::vector`, which is limits the performance especially in optimized code. And I'm net yet talking about the costs of frequent allocations/deallocations necessary for a `std::list`. 
Of course with a `std::vector` you have to be careful when and how elements are removed, ideally remove all elements at once. So using a separate `vector` to store elements to be removed and then in a final pass remove all elements at once might even improve performance.

Comment: @Constantinius Good points -- and from what I can tell from the code, the order of the particle collection might not be significant, in which case you could remove elements by swapping them to the end and then pop-ing them.  If that's the case, then a vector would definitely be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1. You should use `p->m_Targets.erase(t);` rather than `p->m_Targets.remove(*t)`.  In particular, since you're using `remove()`, which takes a value, the std::list class must scan through the entire list to find the value you specify.
2. Removing an element from a list invalidates any iterators that point at that element.  So your `t` iterator is getting invalidated.  Using an invalid iterator has undefined behavior.  Luckily, it's (relatively) easy to solve.  Try something like this:

   ```
   std::list<Target>::iterator t = m_Targets.begin(); 
   while (t != m_Targets.end())
   {
       if( t->checkParticle( p->m_Position ) )
       {
           p->m_ColorChange = Color( CM_HSV, t->m_fHue, t->m_fSat * 0.9f, 1.0f );
           if( p->checkTarget( *t ) )
           {
               t->addParticleHit();
           }
           ++t;
       }
       else
       {
           t = p->m_Targets.erase(t);
       }
   }
   ```

Note that we only do "++t" if we don't remove an element (and *not* on every iteration through the loop, as you did with your for loop).

There's a similar bug in your outer loop.  Replace this:

```
        if( p->m_bIsDead )
        {
            p = m_Particles.erase(p);
        }   
        p++;
```

with this:

```
        if( p->m_bIsDead )
            p = m_Particles.erase(p);
        else
            ++p;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It has the same performance problem, using your suggestions.

What about the lines:
if( p->m_bIsDead )
  {
   p = m_Particles.erase(p);
   // std::cout<<"particle sizes"<<m_Particles.size()<<std::endl;
  
  }

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: updated response to describe bug in the outer loop, and the fact that you shouldn't increment your iterator if you just deleted an element, because that would cause you to skip over an element.

Comment: This line fails compiling
            t = p->m_Targets.remove(t);
I even used 
t = p->m_Targets.erase(t); 
It crashes